# Permissions on phpmyadmin config.inc.php with on elastic beanstalk using .config file

Tags: json, phpmyadmin, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, file-permissions, ebcli

i installed phpmyadmin on elastic beanstalk application and i got the following error "Wrong permissions on configuration file, should not be world writable!"

every time i deploy code to the application i have to go on server and change manually the file permission,

i tried to add a .config file in the .ebextensions folder to run `sudo chmod 755 /path-to-file` in the log it looks good but in fact it's still 666

here is the file

---

> .ebextensions/phpdb.config

```js
container_commands:
    01_change_permissions:
        command: "sudo chmod 000755 /var/app/current/phpdb/config.inc.php"
        ignoreErrors: true
    02_change_permissions:
        command: "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/99_change_permissions.sh"
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/99_change_permissions.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      sudo chmod 000755 /var/app/current/phpdb/config.inc.php
```

Comment: issue was solved by adding the chmod command in the pipeline before zipping the file